# AS3 - Display Coordinates of User Interface Elements

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for a way to determine the display/screen coordinates of a movie clip element.

```
        point = uie.localToGlobal(new Point(uie.x,uie.y));
        posX = point.x + (uie.width  / 2);
        posY = point.y + (uie.height / 2);
```

The code above only retrieves coordinates within the stage. However - I need display/screen coordinates and NOT stage coordinates.

Maybe there is a way to retrieve the display/screen position (top left corner) of the flash container or move the mouse to a position within the stage, retrieve the screen/display and stage position of the mouse and determine an offset between screen position and stage position. Is this possible within (!) AS3?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible within the Flash player. You could try to get the coordinates of the flash container with javascript this will get you a coordinate relative to the browser window. Javascript can get the browser's screen position relative to the desktop. You need the [window.screenLeft](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenleft.asp) api of the browser. With this you can get the position of the flash element on the page and add it to the browser window. This will give you the correct position with a small error margin.

You can also achieve this with Adobe Air. With the [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) api.

```
stage.nativeWindow.x = 0
stage.nativeWindow.y = 0
```

This code snippet will set the window in the top left corner for example.